# Why are resx cultures not found in unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, embedded-resource

I have embedded string resources in my .NET 4.0 project: Strings.resx and Strings.de.resx.

In **production code** the correct localised strings are retrieved, dependent on the value of Strings.Culture:

```
Strings.Culture = new Culture("de");
string deString = Strings.Welcome;  // 'Willkommen'
Strings.Culture = new Culture("en");
string enString = Strings.Welcome;  // 'Welcome'
```

But in my **unit test code** (using MSTest) the strings from 'Strings.de.resx' are never returned - I only ever get the strings from Strings.resx, no matter what the values of `Strings.Culture` or `Threads.CurrentThread.CultureUICulture`.

Can anybody help?

Comment: This usually means that satellite assemblies don't get deployed. What testing framework do you use? For MSTest everything seems to be deployed properly. If something wasn't, you could use DeploymentItemAttribute.

Comment: I'm using MSTest (updated question accordingly). The resx files have Build Action = 'Embedded Resource' in the assembly being tested. How should I use the DeploymentItemAttribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I was able to reproduce this issue. First of all try to disable deployment. Go to "local.testsettings" and uncheck Deployment -> Enable Deployment. When this flag is checked, VS doesn't seem to be deploying satellite assemblies for me. 
If you do need some deployment item, use DeploymentItemAttribute:

```
[DeploymentItem(
   @".\YourProject\bin\Debug\de\YourProject.resources.dll", @".\de\")]
```

or use the same "Deployment" tab to select appropriate satellite assemblies.