# Wrong culture string from ResourceManager.GetString

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I have a simple unit test and a resource file in another assembly with neutral culture (DataSource.resx) and specific culture (DataSource.fi-FI.resx).

The unit test simply tests that I get the right string in the right language. The unit test works fine if I run it from Visual Studio. But fails if I run it from command-line with mstest - it gets the default culture's string instead of the one I tell it to use.

Even giving the culture as a parameter to ResourceManager.GetString gives the same result.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the translations are in another assembly, but unsure. Any ideas? Thanks!: )

Unit test:

```
var cu = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fi-FI");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cu;
var trans1 = MyResources.Api.DataSource.Source_scrape;
Trace.WriteLine(trans1);
var res = MyResources.Api.DataSource.ResourceManager.GetString("Source_scrape", cu);
Trace.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: Ten second google hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484355/why-are-resx-cultures-not-found-in-unit-tests

Comment: Hadn't found that one, thanks. Doesn't solve my problem, even if it seemed to solve it for them. Will comment there.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using the DeploymentItem attribute (as was hinted in a comment linking to another question). So I decorated my test method (could decorate the whole test class also, I guess) with:

```
     [DeploymentItem("fi-FI/MyResources.resources.dll", "fi-FI")]
```

Not the most elegant solution.